# OpenCV, create image object from bitmap

Tags: opencv

I have a bitmap array already containing an image, then I need to construct an openCV object to manipulate it. The only constructor I see is:

```
cv::imread(fileName...);
```

What are some other ways to create an image from an existing structure?

OpenCV 2.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

get the pointer to data, image channels, and dimensions, and use one of the many, many constructors out there:

```
Mat image(width, height, CV_8UC3, ucharDataPtr);
```

Here, CV_8UC3 is the openCV way to index data types. 8 means 8 bits, U means unsigned - so it's an unsigned char - the default image format. C3 means 3 channels. If your bitmap has an alpha channel, you will write CV_8UC4. IF it is gray, then CV_8UC1, and so on.

**Important:**

This constructor does not copy the data. So make sure to keep the original bitmap object alive while you are using the Mat. If you want to copy it, there is a "withCopy parameter" in the constructor. Just check the docs.

Comment: Mat image(width, height, CV_8UC3, ucharDataPtr).clone() if you want to copy data;

Answer (score 0):

just point an IplImage or cvMat at the array.  structure of a cvMat is as follows:

```
CvMat                      // 2D array
  |-- int   type;          // elements type (uchar,short,int,float,double) and flags
  |-- int   step;          // full row length in bytes
  |-- int   rows, cols;    // dimensions
  |-- int   height, width; // alternative dimensions reference
  |-- union data;
      |-- uchar*  ptr;     // data pointer for an unsigned char matrix
      |-- short*  s;       // data pointer for a short matrix
      |-- int*    i;       // data pointer for an integer matrix
      |-- float*  fl;      // data pointer for a float matrix
      |-- double* db;      // data pointer for a double matrix
```

(http://www.cs.iit.edu/~agam/cs512/lect-notes/opencv-intro/opencv-intro.html)