# picturebox image as a parameter of imread in opencv

Tags: visual-c++, opencv

is there any possibility to read the image from the picture box in vc++ using opencv imread? 
am using the following code,

```
vector< Mat > vImg;

Mat rImg;

vImg.push_back(imread(pictureBox1->Image));

vImg.push_back(imread(pictureBox2->Image));
Stitcher stitcher = Stitcher::createDefault();  
stitcher.stitch(vImg, rImg);
```

but am getting error

Comment: What is `pictureBox1`?

Comment: well, you *definitely*  can't use imread for that task, as it reads *files* .

Comment: @ berak so is there any alternate way to read the image which is present in the picturebox control?

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is initialize the `Mat` object from the `PictureBox` pixel data directly.

1) [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793363/opencv-create-image-object-from-bitmap) is an example and short explanation of how to create a `Mat` object from memory buffer

2) [Here](http://www.cemetech.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5723) you can see how to access the pixel memory of the `PictureBox`, it is better to use `LockBits` to obtain the pointer to the memory and pass that in the constructor, but if you are new to all this you can also get it pixel by pixel.